# Wordpress get_posts (show all attachments) pagination outside of the loop

Tags: wordpress, pagination, infinite-scroll

On one of my Wordpress pages (which is really an image blog site) I'm using masonry.js with the Wordpress function get_posts to dump all attachments to my blog posts and display them in a grid. This works fine. However, there's obviously a lot of images and I was hoping to use the infinitescroll.js with this. The only problem is that the get_posts function, outside the loop, doesn't retain the pagination and therefore the functionality of infinitescroll.js doesn't work.

Here is the code I am using to dump all the attachments:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => null ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_attachment_link($post->ID, true);
        the_excerpt();
    }
}
?>
```

Is there anyway of adding in pagination to the original Wordpress `get_posts()` attachment dump outside of the loop, or can anyone think of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using the 'offset' parameter for get posts.

Basically with each new call to get posts, simply increase your offset amount by the amount of new thumbnails you want to display each time. When the number of thumbnails returned is less than your offset amount, you have reached the end of your posts.

Another solution is to use the pagination parameters of the Wp_Query class. See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) for what these are.